# Speeding up density and contour plots

Tags: graphics

**Possible Slowdown in v11.1**

I have a `DensityPlot` and `ContourPlot` I would like to speed up in V11.1.1. Is there any way to achieve a speed up in the following examples? Perhaps through parallelization or compilation?

```
AbsoluteTiming[
ContourPlot[
      Mod[Floor[-5 Im[Log[Log[Sin[Sin[x - I y] + Sin[y + I x]]]]]], 40], 
      {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
      ContourLines -> False, Frame -> False, Background -> Black, 
      ColorFunction -> (RGBColor[1 - #^1.5, Abs[Sin[2 \[Pi] #]], 
         4 #^2 - 2 # + 3] &), 
      PlotPoints -> 200, Contours -> 45, 
      PerformanceGoal -> "Speed", 
      ContourLabels -> None]
]
(* takes over 20 mins *)
```

[image]

```
AbsoluteTiming[
   DensityPlot[
   Length[FixedPointList[(# - (Cos[#] + #^2/2)/(-Sin[#] + #)) &, 
     x + I y, 10, SameTest -> (Abs[#1 - #2] < 10^-10 &)]], {x, 5, 
    7}, {y, -4, -3}, Mesh -> False, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
   Frame -> False, Axes -> False, 
   PlotPoints -> 200, PerformanceGoal -> "Speed",
   ColorFunction -> (If[# >= 1, RGBColor[0, 0, 0], Hue[1 - 2 #]] &)]]

(* takes over 20 mins *)
```

[image]

Note: part of the problem is that I'd like need to the resolution high by fixing the options `PlotPoints` and `Contours`.

Comment: the both take only seconds for me ( first one ~5 sec second one less than 1 second. )

Comment: @george2079 are you on a supercomputer? that's not possible, can you post the output?

Comment: I stuck my images in the post..   computer is 3GHz / 32Gb.     BTW I tried running without the `Speed` performance goal and *that* was taking a long time.

Comment: @george2079 Thanks, and what version of MMA do you have, what are your exact timings?

Comment: I think most users only have 2.5 GHz/16Gb at most.

Comment: timing is 5.19003 and 0.735705 for the two images. mma 10.1 64 bit windows.  I don't think the machine performance should make that much difference.

Comment: Try adding `Exclusions->None`

Answer (score 1):

This is I think a better way to do that first plot.  The function actually returns only 40 discrete integer values (Which I think is giving `ContourPlot` issues ) so you are better off to essentially generate a raster image.

```
(dat = Table[
     Mod[Floor[-5 Im[Log[Log[Sin[Sin[x - I y] + Sin[y + I x]]]]]], 
       40] /. y -> 1, {x, -3, 3, 6/500}, 
      {y, -3, 3, 6/500}]); // AbsoluteTiming
```

> 385.829

```
ArrayPlot[dat, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]
```

[image]